# Mobile issue: transform: scale() resizes image when clicked

Tags: html, css, transform, scale

I have 4 social icons that have a transform property with a value of scale(1.5) on hover.

```
    .social-icon
        margin: 0 20px
        transition: scale 200ms ease-in-out

        &:hover
            transform: scale(1.5)
```

The hover effect works as intended on desktop, but on a mobile screen clicking the social icons causes them to resize to a scale of 1.5 and stay there. I don't know what is causing this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because mobile devices don't behave the same way with the `:hover` pseudo-class as. The browser has no way of knowing where you're hovering over until you tap the element, and that's when it adds the hover styles. The scaling will go away when you tap elsewhere.

Sadly, there is no CSS solution for this out of the box. You'd need JavaScript. For a purely CSS solution, I recommend you use `@media` queries to assign `:hover` styles only to large viewports, but then you run into tablet issues.

Comment: I guess the best way to handle this may be a media query with a min-width of, say, 1024px and add the hover effect there